# ASP.Net MVC 2.0: EditorFor setting name via attributes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes, editorfor

Just wondering how do I mimic the following using attributes...

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SportProgramIdList, "FormMultiSelectDropDownList", "SportProgramIds")%>
```

I know I can specify the template by using [UIHint("FormMultiSelectDropDownList")] but I am left with the problem with how to set the name...

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess you'll have to create your own CustomAttribute `UINameAttribute`.
You could use the `ModelMetadata` to keep your attribute and then I'm not sure what would be the best way to get it, i guess you would have to overide the `HtmlHelper.EditorFor` Extension without the parameter and pass your attribute to the next.

I'm too lazy and to tired to try for a more complete answer.

look at :

[Why You Don't Need ModelMetadata.Attributes](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/why-you-dont-need-modelmetadataattributes.html)

[ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 2: ModelMetadata](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use the objectAttributes argument

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SportProgramIdList, "FormMultiSelectDropDownList", new { id="SportProgramIds" }) %>>
```

you can use this to set any of the html input attributes

Comment: This convention doesn't work for EditorFor or DisplayFor because you aren't passing in an anonymous HTML attributes object, it is an anonymous ViewData additions object. Adding something here would still require consuming it on a custom editor/display template. An example of this was done in an [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/asp-net-mvc-2-editorfor-and-html-properties/3021176#3021176).