# asp.net mvc adding css to editorfor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to change style of the 'editor for' textbox from MVC, specifically I want to make the textbox larger.

I've tried adding css a few ways, to no avail.

including :

```
<td class="myCss"><%=Html.EditorFor(x => x.NickName)%></td>
```

and

```
<td class="myCss"><%=Html.EditorFor(x => x.NickName, new { @class = "myCss" })%></td>
```

help pls!

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc 2 EditorFor() and html properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/asp-net-mvc-2-editorfor-and-html-properties)

Comment: Is EditorFor a "requirement" or are you open to trying `TextBoxFor`/`TextAreaFor` ?

Comment: I can't believe that you can't do this in a neat way!

Answer (score 8):

robh,

it's difficult to know from your question whether you're looking for a 'generic' or specific solution within your project. as such, i'm going to address the generic - works once, works everywhere solution.

this entails taking a few steps (convention over configuration). basically here's what's required:

- create new folder under
  'views->shared called **Editor Templates**'
- create a new usercotrol (ascx) files 
  under that called 'string.ascx'

now, define that ascx file as per:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model) %>
</div>
<div class="new-editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model) %>
</div>
```

this will now make all 'string' based EditorFor() calls use this 'template'. simply make the class 'new-editor-field' reflect your desired css style for that field. obviously, cook as per your own requirement (i.e. you may not want the LabelFor tat etc..)

hope this helps - tho i have to say, this is just one of a few ways to do this (but is my prefered way).

enjoy

jim

Answer (score 3):

Rather than requiring your input field to have the class directly applied, you could use the following:

```
<div class="editor-field myCss">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nickname)
</div>
```

Which results in roughly the following HTML

```
<div class="editor-field myCss">
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" id="Nickname" name="Nickname" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Then just use the CSS rule to style appropriately

`.myCss input.text-box {font-size: 2em;}`

Comment: What if you're using a framework with pre-supplied Css classes.. you really need to be adding a class to the editorfor (so textboxfor seems to be the solution.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NickName, new { @class = "myCss" })%>
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.NickName, new { cols = "40%", @class = "myCss" })%>
```

Now you can define your attributes because MVC knows what type to use (TextArea).

Comment: I downvoted 1 because he specifically said he wanted to change the EditorFor behaviour, not TextBoxFor.

Comment: I made a comment on the original question asking if `EditorFor` as a **Requirement**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class ="my-css-class"} })
```

Answer (score 0):

Place result of EditorFor inside a div with some class attribute on it, and inside style definition for this class, use !important directive to force accept desired values to anything inside that div.

Comment: This did not work for me in MVC4. The style attribute on the DIV still does not take.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249988/505474

Copied from above link,

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

It works for me...