# MVC 3 Editor Template with DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to change this code from MVC2

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>

  <%=Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" }) %>
```

To MVC 3 using Razor.

You can find the full post of what I want to do [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

Comment: Can anybody drop a link to the datePicker jQuery file?

Comment: +1 The first parameter is supposed to be the name of the textbox field right? I assume that it will default by some mechanism to the correct value if it's passed an empty string...