# How can I format a DateTime in a Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have variables like:

```
DateTime crd = a.CreationDate; //(shown as a variable in C# but available in razor views)
```

I want to show these as a date using the format: 11/06/2011 02:11

Ideally I would like to have some kind of HTML helper for this. Anyone out there already have something that might meet my needs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting DateTime format using razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could create a Display Template or Editor Template like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249955/mvc-3-editor-template-with-datetime/4249988#4249988), but the format would apply to all DateTime variables in the given scope (maybe good or bad).

Using the [DisplayFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute works well to define formats for individual fields.

Remember to use `@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.crd)` and/or `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.crd)` syntax for either of the above.

You can always use the [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method in your views as well for more ad hoc formatting.

```
@crd.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") // time using a 24-hour clock
```

Comment: Make sure you also specify ApplyFormatInEditMode = true for the DisplayFormat attribute.

Answer (score 19):

in your model you can set  [[DisplayFormat]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute with formatting as you wish

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
pubilc DateTime CreationDate{ get; set }
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested with my own date format, so copied your extract attribute but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, spoke to quickly. I was using @Model.DateOfBirth but in order for the DisplayFormat attribute to work you need to use @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfBirth).

Comment: This does not not work me. I am rendering the field like this: `<input asp-for="Birthdate" type="date" class="form-control">` is that correct?

Comment: you might need ApplyFormatInEditMode = true in the data annotation, like this...  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to format your date:

```
@string.Format("{0:ddd}",Convert.ToDateTime(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Booking.BookingFromDate).ToString()))
```

If your date field with required attribute then you don't want to validate `null` value. 
Other wise you can use ternary operator

Comment: This answer should be improved.

Answer (score 4):

How about

> @crd.ToShortDateString()

Answer (score 1):

Try Razor View

@Html.Raw(item.Today_Date.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))

Comment: Or Try @Html.Raw(item.Today_Date.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, you could also use string interpolation. I don't think this was an available feature when this question was asked.

```
@($"{crd:dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm}")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Answer (score -2):

If you have a list of dates and want to grab the first:

```
Begin Date: @string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Model.aList.Where(z => z.Counter == 1).Select(z => z.Begin_date).First()))
```