# Html attributes for EditorFor() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

Why can't I pass in html attributes to `EditorFor()`? eg;

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Control.PeriodType, 
    new { disabled = "disabled", readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

I don't want to use metadata

**Update**: The solution was to call this from the view :

```
 <%=Html.EditorFor( model => model.Control.PeriodEndDate, new {Modifiable=model.Control.PeriodEndDateModifiable})%>
```

and use `ViewData["Modifiable"]` in my custom EditorTemplates/String.ascx where I have some view logic that determines whether to add readonly and/or disabled attributes to the input
The anonymous object passed into `EditorFor()` is a parameter called `additionalViewData` and its properties are passed to the editor template in the `ViewData` collection.

Comment: Seriously, still in MVC3 this limitation has no sense and it is really annoying. People around the world are spending time and pulling their hair out with this nonsense. I am sending this to Microsoft Connect.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764012/allow-htmlattributes-in-asp-net-mvc-editorfor

Comment: Is it just me, or does that seem like a lot of bs for something that should be soooo simple?

Comment: Maybe this will help you:

[EditorFor-Implementation with CSS classes and HTML attributes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675708/how-to-customize-the-editorfor-css-with-razor/14687322#14687322

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditorFor() and html properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/editorfor-and-html-properties)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`EditorFor` works with metadata, so if you want to add html attributes you [could always do it](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx). Another option is to simply write a custom template and use `TextBoxFor`:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Control.PeriodType, 
    new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

Comment: The metadata won't work because the html attributes vary depending on other properties in the model, in other words domain or viemodel logic  should determine the html attributes not static metadata. Or am I missing the point, can I set metadata dynamically?

Comment: What is `PeriodType`? Isn't it a simple property? If it is a complex object you could could customize the whole template by placing a partial in `~/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/SomeType.ascx` where `SomeType` is the type name of the `PeriodType` property.

Comment: Also your suggested code would mean passing the whole model into a partial template which accesses a specific property, this would mean I have a partial for each property?

Comment: PeriodType is a simple object, but it may not be editable at the front end depending on domain permissions and workflow

Comment: I get you now. I can use <%=Html.EditorFor( model => model.Control.PeriodEndDate, new {Modifiable=model.Control.PeriodEndDateModifiable})%> and use ViewData["PeriodEndDateModifiable"] in my custom EditorTemplates/String.ascx. Thanks

Comment: Really boring workaround. People, vote up! http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3183610-allow-htmlattributes-in-asp-mvc-editorfor

Comment: @JuniorMayhé, I wouldn't call this a boring limitation. If you think more carefully you will understand that this makes sense. In fact the whole point of the EditorFor helper is that you could have a corresponding template. This template could contain any markup. Not necessarily a single element. It would make absolutely no sense to define `@class` for an editor template that contains 3 divs for example. The Html.TextBoxFor helper allows you to define this because you know what this helper generates - a textbox so it makes sense to define a class to an input element.

Comment: Indeed a class for 3 divs has no sense. The exception would be if the `EditorFor` had no template to look for. The possibility to better handle html attributes would be nicer avoiding workarounds we see today in internet. Imagine a helper: `EditorFor(m=>m.YourField, renderAsSingleInput, htmlAttributesHere)`, that would save time for people who need to stick with EditorFor methods.

Answer (score 126):

**Update** MVC 5.1 now supports the below approach directly, so it works for built in editor too. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#new-features
(It's either a case of Great mind thinking alike or they read my answer :)

**End Update**

If your using your own editor template or with MVC 5.1 which now supports the below approach directly for built in editors.

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.YourProperty, 
  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class="verificationStatusSelect", style = "Width:50px"  } })
```

then in your template (not required for simple types in MVC 5.1)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

Comment: This new feature perfectly solves the original problem asked four years ago.

Comment: If instead of TextBoxFor and helpers like that I use tons of custom editor templates, I would not say it's a fantastic idea to add ViewData[...] into each of them... :(

Answer (score 43):

As of MVC 5.1, you can now do the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#new-features

Comment: The above link is dead. This is available in MVC 5.1, more info here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#new-features

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the link as well.

Comment: how to merge htmlAttributes ?

Comment: This only works with the built in / default `EditorFor` templates. If you implement your own, you have to follow AntonK's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Now **ASP.Net MVC 5.1** got a built in support for it.

[From Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes)

> We now allow passing in HTML attributes in EditorFor as an anonymous
>   object.

For example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, 
              new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **VB.Net code** syntax for **html attributes in MVC 5.1** EditorFor

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.myStringProp, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "myCssClass", .maxlength="30"}}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Control.PeriodType)
```

Comment: One reason is that DisplayFor doesn't render an input, so the value is lost on postback.

Comment: Another reason is the specific scenario where the editor is currently-but-not-always locked, and you want to communicate that the data is potentially editable - just not now.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Metadata you can use a `[UIHint("PeriodType")]` attribute to decorate the property or if its a complex type you don't have to decorate anything.  EditorFor will then look for a PeriodType.aspx or ascx file in the EditorTemplates folder and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks, I may end up doing that if the if/else in my editor template is only required for certain fields

Comment: I though you said you couldn't change the model (not your code), so decorating with UIHint directly would not be an option.

Answer (score 2):

I've been wrestling with the same issue today for a checkbox that binds to a nullable bool, and since I can't change my model (not my code) I had to come up with a better way of handling this.  It's a bit brute force, but it should work for 99% of cases I might encounter.  You'd obviously have to do some manual population of valid attributes for each input type, but I think I've gotten all of them for checkbox.

In my Boolean.cshtml editor template:

```
@model bool?

@{
    var attribs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var validAttribs = new string[] {"style", "class", "checked", "@class",
        "classname","id", "required", "value", "disabled", "readonly", 
        "accesskey", "lang", "tabindex", "title", "onblur", "onfocus", 
        "onclick", "onchange", "ondblclick", "onmousedown", "onmousemove", 
        "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onselect"};
    foreach (var item in ViewData) 
    {
        if (item.Key.ToLower().IndexOf("data_") == 0 || item.Key.ToLower().IndexOf("aria_") == 0) 
        {
            attribs.Add(item.Key.Replace('_', '-'), item.Value);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (validAttribs.Contains(item.Key.ToLower()))
            {
                attribs.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Html.CheckBox("", Model.GetValueOrDefault(), attribs)
```

Comment: I added `Dictionary<string,string> attribs = new Dictionary<string,string>();` and `attribs.Add("tabindex","16");` in one of those `@( )` blocks at the top of my page.  Then I did `@Html.CheckBox("IsActive", Model.IsActive.HasValue ? Model.IsActive : false, attribs)` on my page and it gives me an error:  "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyProject.Models.MyObject>' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBox' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.InputExtensions.CheckBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string.bool, object)' has some invalid arguments".

Answer (score 2):

You can still use EditorFor. Just pass the style/whichever html attribute as ViewData.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourProperty, new { style = "Width:50px" })
```

Because EditorFor uses templates to render, you could override the default template for your property and simply pass the style attribute as ViewData.

So your EditorTemplate would like the following:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<object>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = "text ui-widget-content", style=ViewData["style"] })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Control.PeriodType, 
    new { @class="text-box single-line"})
```

you can use like this ; same output with `Html.EditorFor` ,and you can add your html attributes

Comment: Except `TextBoxFor` ignores any type of `DisplayFormat` that you may be attempting to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own template for the type in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyTypeEditor.vbhtml

```
@ModelType MyType

@ModelType MyType
@Code
    Dim name As String = ViewData("ControlId")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) Then
        name = "MyTypeEditor"
    End If
End Code

' Mark-up for MyType Editor
@Html.TextBox(name, Model, New With {.style = "width:65px;background-color:yellow"})
```

Invoke editor from your view with the model property:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.MyTypeProperty, "MyTypeEditor", New {.ControlId = "uniqueId"})
```

Pardon the VB syntax.  That's just how we roll.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to create an HTML5 number input editor template that could receive additional attributes. A neater approach would be to write your own HTML Helper, but since I already had my .ascx template, I went with this approach:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<input id="<%= Regex.Replace(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""), @"[\[\]]", "_") %>" name="<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>" type="number" value="<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue %>"
<% if (ViewData["attributes"] != null)
   {
       Dictionary<string, string> attributes = (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewData["attributes"];
       foreach (string attributeName in attributes.Keys){%>
        <%= String.Format(" {0}=\"{1}\"", attributeName, attributes[attributeName])%>
       <% }
   } %> />
```

This ugly bit creates a number type input and looks for a ViewData Dictionary with the key "attributes". It will iterate through the dictionary adding its key/value pairs as attributes. The Regex in the ID attribute is unrelated and is there because when used in a collection, `GetFullHtmlFieldId()` returns an id containing square brackets `[]` which it would normally escape as underscores.

This template is then called like this:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity, "NumberField", new { attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "class", "txtQuantity" } } }
```

Verbose, but it works. You could probably use reflection in the template to use property names as attribute names instead of using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Set the condition using `ViewData` in the controller

```
ViewData["Modifiable"] = model.recProcessed;
```

Then use this viewdata in editor template to set the html attribute of the control

```
@Html.RadioButton(prefix, li.Value, li.Selected, @ViewData["Modifiable"].ToString().ToLower() == "true" ? (object)new  { @id = li.Value, @disabled = "disabled" } : new { @id = li.Value })
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC 5.1 and higher solution (will merge local HtmlAttributes and defined in the EditorTemplates):

Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark }.ToExpando().MergeHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"].ToExpando()))
```

Extensions:

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> MergeHtmlAttributes(this ExpandoObject source1, dynamic source2)
{
    Condition.Requires(source1, "source1").IsNotNull().IsLongerThan(0);

    IDictionary<string, object> result = source2 == null
        ? new Dictionary<string, object>()
        : (IDictionary<string, object>) source2;

    var dictionary1 = (IDictionary<string, object>) source1;

    string[] commonKeys = result.Keys.Where(dictionary1.ContainsKey).ToArray();
    foreach (var key in commonKeys)
    {
        result[key] = string.Format("{0} {1}", dictionary1[key], result[key]);
    }

    foreach (var item in dictionary1.Where(pair => !result.ContainsKey(pair.Key)))
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }

    return result;
}

public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(anonymousObject);
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
        expando.Add(item);
    return (ExpandoObject)expando;
}

public static bool HasProperty(this ExpandoObject expando, string key)
{
    return ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).ContainsKey(key);
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PromotionalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { ng_model = "roomCtrl.searchRoomModel().promoCode" }})
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Except for all data_xxx attributes, where I had to replace _ with - when casting `source1` and `source2` as `IDictionary<string, object>`.
I made this function: 
`private static IDictionary<string, object> ToHtmlAttributesDictionary(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> dico) { return dico.ToDictionary(s => s.Key.Replace('_', '-'), s => s.Value); }`