# Adding style to Editor For

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to apply a Style to the Editor for an element, but I can't make it work; what am I doing wrong?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo,"" ,new Dictionary<string,     string> { { "style", "width:500px" } })
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since [MVC 5.1,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#bootstrap-support-for-editor-templates) you can pass in custom attributes with using the `htmlAttributes` as a key:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**In older MVC versions** there is no way to add html attributes with the `EditorFor` method.
You should create a custom [editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) or use `Html.TextboxFor` istead of `EditorFor`. You should check these topics [topic1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc), [topic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550972/mvc-3-html-editorfor-add-html-attribute-not-work).

Answer (score 8):

You can create own css class and appendd it to your editor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "custom-editor" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 3):

`EditorFor` invokes template views rather than outputting a fixed element, so it doesn't take html attributes as an argument. For something like what you're doing the easiest workaround would be to surround the editor and validation message with another element, and apply the style to that instead:

```
<div style="width: 500px;">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo,"")
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`EditorFor` does not allow for styling as there are no parameters for additional attributes. The reason for this is because the EditorFor doesn't always generate a single element as it can be overridden. To style a specific type of element you need to use the specific editor you want to use. For instance if the editor is a textbox just use `TextBoxFor` and apply the styling that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClienteNuevo, "", new { @class = "yourclass" })
```

I hope you help