# How to apply styles for @Html.EditorForModel() in MVC4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, styles

I want to apply for styles to @Html.EditorForModel(). Here is code snippet

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { area = "", returnUrl = returnUrl }, FormMethod.Post)) {
  using (Html.BtFieldset(Loc("legend", "Credentials"))) {
  @Html.EditorForModel()
  <div class="col-md-offset-4">
    @Button.Submit(ViewResources.Action_Common_Logon)
  </div>
  }
```

Comment: You will need to explain why your snippet doesn't work (does it give you an error?) [Please read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759415/adding-style-to-editor-for This question is asked before

Comment: I need to apply individual styles to the fields which were in the model but it's used as EditorForModel not EditorForLabel or textBox because we can do for then by new {style:'xyz'}.  So how can i do that for this