# Disabling EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a EditorFor HTML helper like this:

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, belowLevel ? disabledHtmlOptions : null)</td>
```

-

```
object disabledHtmlOptions = new { disabled = "disabled" };
```

I wanna make this disabled at every time. How do I do that? I dont want to do data annotations because this property is being used in other views too. Only on this view I want to disable it.

Comment: raj, you risk not getting a great answer here as your description of the problem is a little vague. is there any way to expand on the problem and required solution, perhaps with your example being expanded a little plus the background subtext if possible

Comment: @Jim, I dont know how can I describe it more correctly, however, I only need to disable my textbox or editorfor box where Name is being displayed. I can display in Label but thats not the requirement.

Comment: raj - i think your edit just helped :)

Comment: By the way, be careful with this, because even though the input is disabled your users can still send you a new value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're stuck on using `EditorFor` you could set the disabled attribute via jQuery on page load. I know it's not ideal, but it's the only way unless you create an overload for EditorFor that accepts an htmlAttributes collection

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#Name').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

MVC 5.1 now allows passing in HTML attributes in EditorFor [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706317/2695414). So you could do this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = "disabled" } })
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just render HTML for the view.  If it's meant to be "read-only" just render the text.  Otherwise you could render an `<input>` element.

For example, instead of

```
<td>@Html.EditorFor( m => m.Name )</td>
```

do

```
<td>@Model.Name</td>
```

or

```
<td><input type="text">@Model.Name</input></td>
```

Comment: m does not exist in the current context when I tried this @m.Name ?

Comment: try @Model.Name, (beat me to it @Jisaak).  Updated answer.

Comment: I updated my question. I have an object where I am disabling it. Still it doesnt work.

Comment: @Raj, if you need it disabled, won't my first option work?  Rendering it as text (<td>@Model.Name</td>) will make it uneditable.  If you need a disabled input box, just put disabled="disabled" in the input element itself.  If you need to conditionally add the disabled attribute, you can do that also.

Comment: @contactmatt: So you are saying something like this:         <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, disabled = "disabled" )</td>

Comment: @Raj, I don't think that will work...have you tried doing <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled">@Model.Name</input></td> ?

Comment: @Model.Name will show me something like label form. I dont want it. I want a disabled textbox UI.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the signature of the `EditorFor` method allows you to specify any HTML attributes. You can if you change it to `TextBoxFor` however.

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, belowLevel ? disabledHtmlOptions : null)</td>
```