# Change font size for Mvc TextboxFor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I am struggling to change the font size for MVC TextBoxFor?

I can change the font size when using:

> input, textarea {}

But this changes all my input size's. I also tried to then add a css class to my TextboxFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { @Class = "Mytextarea" })
```

css

```
.Mytextarea {
    font-size: 0.85em !important;
    height: 14px !important;
    color: #333 !important;
    /*font-family: inherit;*/
    width: 300px;

}
```

This has had no affect.

My TextBoxFor's are huge and bulky and i have no way to change them, If possible i would like to set styling to change them all at once.

---

Edit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you see the chrome/firefox debugging tool(press f12) html element section and checked what css class was applied?

Comment: @Murali Yes it says "Text-box single-line" i have no idea where that style is from. That's the class its given, they styling looks like its taking input, dropdown. .... But its a text box :\

Comment: Can you add the snapshot with chrome console? It should be from some css file only

Comment: Are you using any other form plugin? Are you sure the correct view you are looking into it?. I dont see any problem in MVC EditorFor. may be try with small letters @class="yourclass"

Comment: I don't even see .Mytextarea in the debugging window. Is that css rule in your `site.css`?

Comment: @Murali i clicked inspect element so its the correct field. I am using MVC 4 no plugins for the textbox's

Comment: @Blaise yes i added it to my site.css

Comment: Then, are you using bundling? Have you rebuilt the solution?

Comment: @Blaise, look at the html posted. It doesnt have class `Mytextarea`. It mean it was not at all applied. I am suspecting Pomster looking/coded in a different view

Comment: okay, I am guessing if your site.css is referenced in `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`

Comment: I am looking at the screen shot you posted and find `.Mytextarea` is not there.

Comment: Did you try changing it to `@class` as Murali said? If so, try `ctrl+f5` on the page just incase the browser has cached the css file.

Answer (score 2):

So, you start your question off asking about TextBoxFor, but your actual code references EditorFor.

When using the `EditorFor` extension, you need to write a custom editor template to describe the visual components. If you don't, it will use the default template, which is where `"text-box single-line"` is coming from.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675727/1515890) for a quick explanation on how to build a template that you can assign to the `EditorFor` helper. Or just use `TextBoxFor` like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @Class = "Mytextarea" })
```