# What us the purpose of the Editable attribute if not to control editing on a field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Nearly all my properties in my view model are decorated with `[Editable(false)]', but when I scaffold a view, that uses`EditorFor` these properties, they are all still editable on the form.

Must I now manually change all `EditorFor` to `DisplayFor` to prevet editing? OK, I will eventually change the T4 that generates the edit form, but really, what purpose does this attribute serve then?

Comment: +1. Check [THIS](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/07/25/notes-on-templates-and-data-annotations-in-mvc-2.aspx) post

Comment: "what purpose does this attribute serve then" - the data annotations are used by various different parts of the framework, not just MVC. Just because MVC doesn't respect it, doesn't mean that other parts wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

`EditorFor` works with metadata, so if you want to add html attributes you could always do it. Another option is to simply write a custom template and use TextBoxFor:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Control.PeriodType, 
    new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

Extracted from here:

[Html attributes for EditorFor() in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc)