# MVC Editor with data- attribute from model attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build in form hinting for a web application.
The form hints are stored in the "Description" attribute of my ViewModel.

```
public class ViewModel{
  [Description("Field description for input hints")]
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I need to be able to pass these through to my form controls "data-content" field.

```
<input data-content="Field description for input hints" name="Name" class="guidance"/>
```

I'm unable to just use a simple EditorFor as I can't add additional HTML fields to it.

If I create an editor template, I'd obviously need to access the model metadata. I'm unsure how to do this if I'm passing a null model?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Sorry for the conformation in the form of answer due to shortage of rep.

In JQuery can you add Attributes like below

```
$('Some ID').attr('your attr', 'Some Val')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ColName, new { @class = "abc" })
```

Comment: You can't specify htmlAttributes like that when using EditorFor.
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc