# Html Attributes on EditorFor() or Check dataType in EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class with a property Password annotated as DataType.Password like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

When I use EditorFor to show this field on the view, I need to apply a CSS class on it.

I do it the following way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, "loginTextBox", new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "" })
```

For some reason there's no build-in way of using Html attributes for EditorFor() (like I could read here for example: [Html attributes for EditorFor() in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc)), so I needed to create a simple EditorTemplate to allow it like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = ViewData["class"], id = ViewData["id"], placeholder = ViewData["placeholder"]})
```

The problem is that, this editor is shared between other properties which are not DataType.Password. In the case the property is annotated as DataType.Password  I want to use

> @Html.Password(...)

otherwise

> @Html.TextBox(...)

The only way I can think to achieve this is by checking the DataType, but I don't how to do that.

Any idea on how to check the DataType or even a better approach?

Comment: What version of asp.net MVC do you use? ASP.Net MVC 5 supports `html attributes for EditorFor`

Comment: You can write your own EditorTemplate for this purpose specifically.

Comment: That's not true #Murali. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: #jacqijvv I know I could do a specific one, but then the Datatype.Password looses all its meaning.

Comment: @lpaloub, please check out the [ASP.Net MVC 5.1 Release notes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes), `@Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })`

Comment: Check with ModelMetadataProvider value and conditionally render TextBoxFor or Password in EditorFor

Comment: @Murali Brilliant! I was using 5.0 and looks like it comes with 5.1. Exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now ASP.Net MVC 5.1 supports `htmlAttributes` for EditorFor. Just pass this as an anonymous object.

[ASP.Net MVC 5.1 Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, "loginTextBox",
 new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = ""})
```

Comment: That might no be useful to everybody (not everybody can update), but since I was just starting the website this solution came perfect for me. Thanks again!

Comment: how can I use the Prompt metadata with the new EditorFor ?