# Simple Razor question regarding Html.Editor helper (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, editorfor

Basically, I have a table with multiple editors like this:

`<table>

<tr>

   <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Random1)</td>

   <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Random2)</td>

</tr>

<tr>

   <td colspan="2">@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.Random3)</td>

</tr>

</table>`

Now, my problem is, as you probably already figured out from the colspan="2", is that I want my third textbox to stretch all the way thorugh the two columns. In normal HTML is would naturally just add a width attribute. Is there a DataAnnotation like `DataType.MultilineText` that can change the width of the editors? Any other ideas?

UPDATE: If I change it to a TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor, I can actually add `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Random, new { style = "width: 500px;" })`.
Only problem is, I have another textbox (lets say random4) and it somehow overrides my DataAnnotation MultilineText and makes it a plain 500px textbox. Guess ill have to digg into the CSS :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to just style the control in the css. For the random3 textbox ill use `input[type="text"]{width:1px}` and for the random4 multilinetext, ill use just use `textarea{width:1px}`

Answer (score 1):

You might find some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/editorfor-and-html-properties) useful.

The good thing about templates is that if you don't like the way they work, you can simply drop-in your own implementation.

You can also try using CSS to specify the width for your control, based on it's ID.

Comment: Alright, thanks alot. Theres a bunch of different approches in that post, ill look them through and see if theres anything that fits me.

Comment: Wow, there is relativly a lot of effort in solving this reading though that post. You should think this was dead simple.

Comment: The issue is really down to the simplistic way in which the existing templates are defined. They're a simple 'starter for 10'. You can obtain or develop templates with richer functionality; the good thing is that they only need to be developed once, and you can use them over-and-over again. It's quite possible that later versions of MVC will have richer templates, but can you wait?

Comment: Nope :) Check out my update on the question. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score -1):

In the Property of the Model - in this case Random3 give it an annotation

```
public class ViewModelName
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Random3 { get; set; }
}
```

then when you can the Html.EditorFor(x => x.Random3) it will know it needs to be multiline

Comment: Yes I am well aware of that. Thats not my problem. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: Only other way is to control via CSS then I'm afraid :(

Comment: Guess so. Most of the solutions in Steve's answer are too much effort, for something I would think was basic and dead simple.

Comment: Kasper, have you tried using CSS? The ID of the relevant control should be easy enough to find - use View Source in the browser to find it.

Comment: Yep, I really just wanted to avoid it. Guess im not use to style controls in the css. But it works, and thats the most important thing :)