# Where is the single-line?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

In the default newly created MVC3 application, at the CRUD's Create view, the text box is implemented/called up as

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)             
    </div>
```

And the resulted html view file for that block becomes

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The EnrollmentDate field is required." id="EnrollmentDate" name="EnrollmentDate" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EnrollmentDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>             
        </div>
```

I look up the class single-line in the Site.css but I can't find it anywhere, only multi-line there is [:-D silly inversion].

Could someone tell me where it is ? is it a css keyword ?

Second, I don't know the difference between using EditFor member function from Html class and TextBox function also from Html especially when I would like to add new style elements to the textbox.

[**EDIT**]
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

I am reading that tutorial

Comment: See here for overriding the EditorFor functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/editorfor-and-html-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an emitted class attribute from a built-in editor template.  This article explains them quite well.

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a CSS style but it is not defined in the Site.css, the CSS that is applied in that instance is **text-box** and **input[type="text"]**.

```
.text-box {
width: 30em;
```

}

```
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: #444;
width: 200px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use 
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name, new {@class="class-name"})` 
instead of 
`@Html.EditorFor()`