# @Html.EditorFor How to make attribute type="email"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I can do this easily using a `TextBoxFor` but how do I do it with an `EditorFor`?

I figured using the DataAnnotation `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` but that doesn't do it.

I don't quite understand what the `DataType` annotation actually does because it doesn't seem to do anything at all at first glance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `EditorFor` helper method is somewhat limited out of the box and doesn't yet appear to support the HTML5 `type="email"` attribute.

Your options right now seem to be either using `TextBoxFor` or creating a custom template that will allow you to set the input's `type` attribute. Here's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/editorfor-and-html-properties) that reviews some of the options for creating your own templates.

The `DataAnnotation [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` is actually quite useful. It sets the `id` and `name` of your form field to `email`, which you can use with jQuery validation to show the user client-side validation messages. Applying the `DataAnnotation` to your model class also means that the email property on your model will be automatically validated on the server side. If you enable unobtrusive validation in your app, you get client- and servers-side validation almost for free.

Comment: Cannot make this happen even with TextBoxFor

Answer (score 17):

You can override the HTML Attributes, to which a browser will fallback to `type='text'` if they do not support it:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email" })`

Answer (score 15):

it seems to be supported now.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email" } })
```

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to **jortizromo**'s answer, you have now at least two options:

1. Specifying `@type` in the `htmlAttributes` parameter for method `EditorFor()` as in

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "email" } })
   ```
2. Using the `EmailAddress` annotation attribute from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace in the model class definition for the corresponding `Email` property and a simple call to method EditorFor() (this provides HTML validation data tags which could be a good or bad idea depending on your task) as in

   ViewModel

   ```
   [EmailAddress]
   public string Email { get; set; }
   ```

   Razor View

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
   ```