# How Can I Conditionally disable the @HtmlEditorFor Based on Model Id ASP.NET Mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I would like to conditionally disable this button, or hide it, if Model.Promotion.PromotionID is 10. Not sure how to do it.
i am attempted to find the solution but struggling with it.

Would appreciate some help thanks

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Promotion", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionID)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Promotion.Active)


    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend">Edit Promotion</legend>

        <div>

        <div class="editor-field" title="The name of the Promotion"  @((Model.Promotion.PromotionID == 209) ? "disabled" : "")>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionTitle )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Promotion.PromotionTitle)
                </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Disabling a DIV won't do anything. You'd need to disable the Razor call.

Comment: @krillgar do you have an example?

Comment: I don't use `.EditorFor`, so there are [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625327/editorfor-and-html-properties), or [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Object%29) that can help.

Comment: `@if (Model.Model.Promotion.PromotionID == 209) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Promotion.PromotionTitle ) controls } else { // generate html above }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke generate what html above can you put it in a block of code if you dont mind

Comment: Its just your `@Html.EditorFor()` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` lines of code

Comment: @StephenMuecke i understand your code but what im trying to do is to disable all the html if the promotion ID == 209 so if Model.Model.Promotion.Promotion ID  == 209 ? disabled = "disabled) etc but this is not working

Comment: What in the world for. Disabled controls do not submit a value so you may as well just use `DisplayFor()` (and style it to look like a disabled textbox it that is what you want. And there no point rendering a pointless `ValidationMessageFor()` if the control is disabled (and there is no such thing as a disabled div)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i misunderstood your concept earlier i now get the displayfor will just display the data which means that the user wont be able to edit it